# Communication issues between two Netty socket applications (partial messages) from socket-based communication

Tags: java, netty

I'm experiencing communication issues while testing between two Netty socket applications (the main application, and the integration test application), where I've been receiving an unusual amount of partial messages.

One pattern being noticed, is that the ***first*** message being sent from the test application (application executes sending the message from outside the pipeline, using a sharable handler) tends to always be partial. This is also noticed during times of latency, where another issue occurs.

The other issue is that when a partial message is receive at times, the decoder seems to be trapped in a loop, where it continues try to read the partial message indefinitely. I have a unit test to simulate the partial message using `EmbeddedChannel`, but the unit test is not replicating what I am seeing during the integration test.

The main application is using the following pipeline:

```
ch.pipeline().addLast(<HeaderTrailerFrameDecoder>, <NettyMessageDecoder>, <HeaderTrailerFrameEncoder>, <NettyMessageEncoder>);
ch.pipeline().addLast(<IdleStateHandler>,<EventHandler>, <ChannelHandler>);
```

where:

- `HeaderTrailerFrameDecoder` - Removes single-byte frame from beginning / end of packet
- `NettyMessageDecoder` - Converts message from ByteBuf to domain object
- `HeaderTrailerFrameEncoder` - Appends frame to message packets
- `NettyMessageEncoder` - Converts message from domain object to ByteBuf
- `IdleStateHandler` - Netty class, detects stale / idle connections
- `EventHandler` - Sharable handler to send messages from outside of the pipeline
- `ChannelHandler` - Main handler for all business logic

I'm thinking the problem could be with all of the encoders / decoders, and not releasing my ByteBuf objects perhaps? I'm only seeing the issue from the first decoder, the `HeaderTrailerFrameDecoder`, so I'll provide a snippet below. For every connection, the first message coming through from a series of messages being sent by the test application, first produces the log `msg="could not find trailer"`.

```java
@Slf4j // Lombok logging
public class HeaderTrailerFrameDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

    private final byte header;
    private final byte trailer;

    HeaderTrailerFrameDecoder(byte header, byte trailer) {
        this.header = header;
        this.trailer = trailer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(
            final ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
            final ByteBuf buf,
            final List<Object> out) {
        log.trace("msg=\"decoding message with header and trailer\", buf={}", buf);

        // Find header
        int headerIndex = buf.forEachByte(value -> value != header);
        if (headerIndex < 0) {
            log.error("msg=\"could not find header\", payload=\"{}\"", payload);
            buf.skipBytes(buf.readableBytes());
            return;
        }
        int beforeHeaderLen = headerIndex - buf.readerIndex();
        buf.skipBytes(beforeHeaderLen + 1);


        // Find trailer
        int trailerIndex = buf.forEachByte(value -> value != trailer);
        if (trailerIndex < 0) {
            String payload = debug(buf);
            log.error("msg=\"could not find trailer\"");
            buf.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }
        int insideFrameLen = trailerIndex - buf.readerIndex();
        ByteBuf frame = buf.readBytes(insideFrameLen);
        buf.skipBytes(1);

        // Pass message through
        out.add(frame);
    }
}
```